# find the products with only one image

Tags: image, base-url, thumbnail, small-image

we have some 1000 products in site.

for some products we uploaded 1, for some2 .... for some 5 images.

if we upload only one image, than for that image we selected small, base, thumbinal in backend

we exported all products using `system > import/export> export all produts`.

but in csv under small, base, thumbinal columns , we can see that image name.

its going to be manual process if we check like this.

is there any way we can find the products with only one image

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use bellow custom code for the images count

```
$products  = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection();
        foreach($products as $product) {
            $product->load();
            $galleryData = $product->getData('media_gallery');
            echo "Product Sku: ".$product->getSku()." & Image count : ".count($galleryData['images']);
            echo '<br>';
        }
```

If your need only image products then use code

```
 $products  = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection();
        foreach($products as $product) {
            $product->load();
            $galleryData = $product->getData('media_gallery');
            if(count($galleryData['images'])==1) {
                echo "Product Sku: ".$product->getSku();

            }
            echo '<br>';
        }
        }
```

Comment: i will check it.....

Comment: i used your code for images count : http://pastebin.com/6ptxm7VL and placed this file in root

of the site and opened in broswer, but i am getting error as like this :

http://hotwheelstoys.in/one/em0113-full-package/clone.php

when i used code for only one image, its displaying blank page in browser.....

Comment: Please add code in your file

<?php
require_once('app/Mage.php');
Mage::app('default');

class TEST
{
 public function index()    
    { 
     $products  = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection();
     foreach($products as $product) {
      $product->load($product->getId());
   $galleryData = $product->getData('media_gallery');
   $galleryData = $product->getData('media_gallery');
            echo "Product Sku: ".$product->getSku()." & Image count : ".count($galleryData['images']);
            echo '<br>';
  }
 }
    
   
}

$obj = new TEST();
$obj->index();
?>

Comment: now its displaying blank page :  http://hotwheelstoys.in/one/em0113-full-package/clone.php

Comment: but it is working my end

Comment: please check this once again : http://pastebin.com/YsCMfLjC

seems somewhere i am missing, please check this..... is it related to file permission or what else ?

Comment: i placed this file in root of the site and opening this file from browser...., where i am missing?

Comment: You are doing wrong way. Can you please add only my code in file. Please create new file test.php on root and put my bellow code in file

Comment: <?php
require_once('app/Mage.php');
Mage::app('default');

class TEST
{
 public function index()    
    { 
     $products  = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection();
     foreach($products as $product) {
      $product->load($product->getId());
   $galleryData = $product->getData('media_gallery');
   $galleryData = $product->getData('media_gallery');
            echo "Product Sku: ".$product->getSku()." & Image count : ".count($galleryData['images']);
            echo '<br>';
  }
 }
    
   
}

$obj = new TEST();
$obj->index();
?>

Comment: for both code , its displaying all images products : http://pastebin.com/Mh9sKvjy, please check

http://hotwheelstoys.in/one/em0113-full-package/cloneall.php

Comment: please give complete code to list one image products.....

Comment: its working fine : http://hotwheelstoys.in/one/em0113-full-package/clone1.php

but its taking more space product after product. please help me to reduce the space.

Comment: Please use code :<?php
require_once('app/Mage.php');
Mage::app('default');

class TEST
{
 public function index()    
    { 
     $products  = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection();
     foreach($products as $product) {
      $product->load($product->getId());
   $galleryData = $product->getData('media_gallery');
   if($product->getSku()) {
    echo "Product Sku: ".$product->getSku()." & Image count : ".count($galleryData['images']);
             echo '<br>';
   }
            
  }
 }
    
   
}

$obj = new TEST();
$obj->index();
??

Comment: If comment help full then add vote me...:)

Comment: its again giving blank page : http://hotwheelstoys.in/one/em0113-full-package/clone1.php please check....

Comment: thnaks a lot @Abdul

Comment: its my duty , i did it....